# How to start a new match offline

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm playing CSGO offline with bots. After all of the enemies have died and all of the objectives have been completed and the time is up, the game won't start a new match. I've tried vanilla maps and I've tried multiple workshop maps, but I still get the same exact problem. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You mean that the vote doesn't pop up? Have you ever made any changes to the `mapgroup`? Also you can try this `mp_endmatch_votenextmap 1` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here, start a new offline match and type

```
mp_ignore_round_win_conditions 0
```

I can't explain why this happens but the problem shouldn't persist after you've entered the command.